# ASP.NET Hyperlink binding multiple URL parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

i got this code:

```
http://localhost:52182/ReviewRequest.aspx?requestid=254351496
```

where the setting behind it in the asp.net page is:

```
     <asp:HyperLinkField
                DataNavigateUrlFields="Request_No"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ReviewRequest.aspx?requestid={0}"
                 DataTextField="Request_No"
                 HeaderText="Access Request"
                 DataTextFormatString="Review Request"
                 SortExpression="Request_No" />
```

the question is: in the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property in code above, what is the {0} stand for? and I want to pass another dynamically set parameter in the same URl so to look like this

```
http://localhost:52182/ReviewRequest.aspx?requestid=254351496&nid=xxxxxx
```

how can I do so?

Thanks, and help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `{0}` is the zero indexed value of the fields you have mentioned in `DataNavigateUrlFields`. You can pass the next field as

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField
                DataNavigateUrlFields="Request_No, NID"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ReviewRequest.aspx?requestid={0}&nid={1}"
```

Comment: perfect! just what I needed to know :D Thanks a lot